# Merge Sort throwing error

Tags: java, mergesort

I am writing a merge sort and I'm getting an `arrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
public class MergeSort {

    private int[] helper; 
    private int[] numbers; 

    private int number; 

    //sort method
    public MergeSort(int[] values){
        this.numbers = values; 
        this.number = values.length; 
        this.helper = new int[number]; 
        merge(0, number-1); 
    }

    //mergeSort method
    public void merge(int low, int high){
        if(low<high){
            int mid =(low+high)/2;  
            merge(low, mid); 
            merge(mid+1, high); 
            combine(low, mid, high);  
        }
    }
    //merge method
    public void combine(int low, int mid, int high){
        //copy numbers into helper array;
        for(int ii=0;ii<high;ii++){
            this.helper[ii]=this.numbers[ii]; 
        }
        int ii = low;
        int jj = mid+1;
        int kk = high; 
        while((ii <= mid) && (jj<=high)){

            if(helper[ii] <= helper[jj]){
                    //error is thrown here
                this.numbers[kk] = this.helper[ii];
                ii++; 
            }else{
                this.numbers[kk] = this.helper[jj]; 
                jj++; 
            }
            kk++;
        }
        while(ii<=mid){
            this.numbers[kk]=this.helper[ii]; 
            kk++;
            ii++;
        }

    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = new int[]{2,6,1,9,12,64,32,23,12,90,87}; 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MergeSort ms = new MergeSort(values); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ms.numbers)); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Apologies - I missed that comment. So, what are the local variables when the exception is thrown?

Comment: `ii=6` and both arrays have 10 elements

Comment: Note: error was one line below. Sorry for that. See code for update.

Comment: So it must be `kk` then. Keep going `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues, but try the following code:

```
public class MergeSort {

    private int[] helper;
    private int[] numbers;

    private int number;

    //sort method
    public MergeSort(int[] values){
        this.numbers = values;
        this.number = values.length;
        this.helper = new int[number];
        merge(0, number-1);
    }

    //mergeSort method
    public void merge(int low, int high){
        if(low<high){
            int mid =(low+high)/2;
            merge(low, mid);
            merge(mid+1, high);
            combine(low, mid, high);
        }
    }
    //merge method
    public void combine(int low, int mid, int high){
        //copy numbers into helper array;
        for(int ii=low;ii<=high;ii++){
            this.helper[ii]=this.numbers[ii];
        }
        int ii = low;
        int jj = mid+1;
        int kk = low;
        while((ii <= mid) && (jj<=high)){
            if(helper[ii] <= helper[jj]){
                this.numbers[kk] = this.helper[ii];
                ii++;
            }else{
                this.numbers[kk] = this.helper[jj];
                jj++;
            }
            kk++;
        }
        while(ii<=mid){
            this.numbers[kk]=this.helper[ii];
            kk++;
            ii++;
        }

    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = new int[]{2,6,1,9,12,64,32,23,12,90,87};
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MergeSort ms = new MergeSort(values);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ms.numbers));
    }

}
```

Comment: What's different? I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Loop changes from `for(int ii=0;ii<high;ii++){` to `for(int ii=low;ii<=high;ii++){`
also `int kk=low;`, not `int kk=high;`.

Comment: You can't do `ii<=high` because you'll get that same exception. However, you were right about `kk=low`. Change your answer and I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: If I use `ii<high` instead, the code gives me the array `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]` as the result. That's because the `combine` method doesn't copy the last value (since you're using inclusive indexing). Testing with `ii<=high` didn't throw an exception for me and gave the correct result. Could you double check?